# How to install python with conda?

Tags: python, conda, python-3.9

I'm trying to install python 3.9 in a conda enviroment. I tried creating a new conda env using the following command,

```
conda create --name myenv python=3.9
```

But I got an error saying package not found because python 3.9 is not yet released

So, I manually created a folder in `envs` folder and tried to list all envs. But I couldn't get the manually created new environment.

So, how do I install python 3.9 in a conda env with all functionalities like `pip` working?

Comment: This can be installed via conda with the command conda install -c anaconda python=3.9 as per https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python.

Comment: running conda update --all may resolve some dependency failures.

Comment: @SumitYadav It won't work

Comment: Is python3.9 released yet?

Comment: It's not on any channels yet, so not possible at the moment. If you really must use it, install it natively and try to keep it separate from your Conda envs/installation.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

To create python 3.11 conda environment use the following command

```
conda create -n py311 python=3.11
```

```
py311 - environment name
```

#### Update 3

To create python 3.10 conda environment use the following command

```
conda create -n py310 python=3.10
```

```
py310 - environment name
```

#### Update 2

You can now directly create python 3.9 environment using the following command

```
conda create -n py39 python=3.9
```

```
py39 - environment name
```

#### Update 1

Python 3.9 is now available in conda-forge.

To download the tar file - https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python/3.9.0/download/linux-64/python-3.9.0-h852b56e_0_cpython.tar.bz2

Anaconda Page - https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python

---

As pointed out in the comments, python 3.9 is not yet there on any channels. So, it cannot be install yet via conda.

Instead, you can download the python 3.9 executable and install it.

Once the installation is done, a new executable will be created for python 3.9 and pip 3.9 will be created.

Python:

```
python3.7          
python3.7-config   
python3.7m         
python3.7m-config  
python3.9          
python3.9-config
```

pip

```
pip      
pip3     
pip3.7   
pip3.8   
pip3.9   
pipreqs
```

In order to install ipython for python 3.9,

```
pip3.9 install ipython
```

Comment: Is the information on installing Python 3.9 directly, pip, etc. really necessary?

Comment: Why? As far as I can tell, it's more or less the same procedure for installing any version of Python 3, right?

Comment: Most folks use `python3.x -m pip` to run the PIP that belongs to a specific release of Python. This is particularly important when using virtual environments like those created by conda.

Comment: `python -m pip` is the recommended way to call pip. Not `pip`.

Comment: I did this and still when I type `python --version` I get `Python 3.7.9`.  Do I need to set my environment to the newly created environment?

Comment: @Addem you need to activate your newly created environment - `conda activate py39`

Comment: what's meaning of that  "-n"

Comment: `-n` - environment name

Comment: Does not Work --->`$ conda create -n demo-py39 python=3.9 \

Fetching package metadata ........... \

PackageNotFoundError: Package missing in current win-64 channels:
  - python 3.9*
` BUT this DOES WORK `conda create -c conda-forge python=3.9 -n py39-demo`

Comment: @TimothyL.J.Stewart The command is working fine in my Mac. Probably it's the case only with windows I guess

Comment: @bigbounty the culprit was 4.3 `conda --version` the fix was `conda update conda` then this works

Comment: I tried `conda create -n py39 python=3.9`. It did installed python 3.9, but without numpy, pandas etc. It does not make sense to install a conda environment without those packages :(

Comment: @mugi I share your concern.  I created a new Python 3.10 environment on my Windows machine by opening Anaconda Prompt and executing `conda create --name python_3.10 python=3.10`  I noticed that it only downloaded 17 new packages.  After I switched my PyCharm projects to use that new python_3.10 environment, my code now breaks (e.g. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'`).

Comment: I guessed that maybe Python 3.10 is too new, so I tried downgrading to 3.9 via `conda create --name python_3.9 python=3.9`  This was even worse, it only downloaded 12 new packages, and my code is still broken when I try to use that environment.  I am puzzled because [this Anaconda link says that they have 611 packages compatible with Python 3.9](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/packages/py3.9_win-64/).  What are we doing wrong?

Answer (score 23):

On 6-Oct-2020, Python 3.9 was made available on conda-forge: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python. However, most of the other packages (including some of the essentials to create a basic environment) didn't explicitly support Python 3.9 yet.

However (as of 15-Oct-2020), the basic dependencies appear to have been fixed and the following command now works:

```
conda create -c conda-forge python=3.9 -n py39-demo
```

Answer (score 20):

You can now simply just run

`conda create --name myenv python=3.9`

And it will create your python 3.9 virtual environment simply.