# How can I install Python 3.9 from the Anaconda prompt?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, python-3.9

Python 3.9.0rc1 has been released today, according to the [official website](https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/3.9.html).

Is there a way I can use it in an Anaconda environment? I tried

```
conda create --name python39 python==3.9
```

But it says:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python==3.9 (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for python==3.9

Edit: closing as duplicate rules out questions with no answer, and the self-accepted answer to the suggested duplicate *does not answer the question*. It says "use another distribution channel instead".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conda: how to install python3.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63216201/conda-how-to-install-python3-9)

Comment: It's virtually the same question, but closing as duplicate rules out questions with no answer, and the _self-accepted_ answer to your suggested duplicate is really not a working answer.

Comment: @NicolasGervais - I agree. A python 3.9 release candidate was released today, and the 3.9.0 release is [expected to be released on October 5, 2020](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0596/#release-schedule). It seems that both the anaconda and conda-forge channels do not have python release candidates. Compiled Python packages (e.g., numpy) would also need to be built with 3.9, and those also seem to not be available.

Comment: @NicolasGervais As the answer (or the comments) on the duplicate question states, it's not there yet, so as an answer on your question: You can't.

Comment: Not important, but he release date does not match. Changelog says 2020-08-11: https://docs.python.org/3.9/whatsnew/changelog.html#python-3-9-0-release-candidate-1

Comment: "*the self-accepted answer to your suggested duplicate is really not a working answer.*" But no one is stopping anyone from posting *other* answers to the proposed duplicate. This is essentially the same question as that, the answers here could also have been posted there, making for one source of Q&A for "how to install python3.9 with conda".

Comment: @GinoMempin you can tell that to the Stack Overflow staff, who decided to prevent _unanswered_ original questions to be used to close other questions.

Comment: I don't get it. The proposed duplicate was asked on Aug 2 and *answered* on Aug 4. Your question was posted on Sep 3, and *can* be closed as duplicate of the other one. Both Q's ask how to create a Python3.9 env using conda. In the duplicate, the answer was "no, it's not yet possible, but here's a workaround for now". The answers here are *__also__* "no, it's not yet possible" then "here's how to check". None of the answers here offer a "working" solution. No one is stopping anyone from posting *other* answers to the 1st Q&A pair, especially if there is a better answer or an updated answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's preferable to update Conda before installing Python 3.9:

```
conda update -n base -c defaults conda
```

Then install a Python 3.9 environment. This works now:

```
conda create --name python39 python==3.9
```

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.9 is available for download via `conda` on the `conda-forge` channel as of October 9, 2020. See [the Python notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html) and the [conda-forge/python](https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python/files) site.

---

(Copying my comment on the OP's post) A python 3.9 release candidate was released today, and the 3.9.0 release is [expected to be released on October 5, 2020](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0596/#release-schedule). It seems that both the anaconda and conda-forge channels do not have python release candidates. Compiled Python packages (e.g., numpy) would also need to be built with 3.9, and those also seem to not be available.

If you look at https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python, there are several labels available, but none of them includes Python 3.9. The commands

```
conda install -c conda-forge/label/dev python 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/prerelease python
```

both install Python 3.8 for me on amd64 Linux.

The [anaconda channel](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/python) also does not include Python 3.9. You can look in the version dropdown in the "Files" tab. At the time of writing, the latest version is 3.8.5.