# I tried following command to install python 3.9 but my anaconda won't let python go ahead oh 3.7.9 version

Tags: python, anaconda

`Conda install -c anaconda python`
I tried doing it again thinking that it might go one step further but it shows that all requested packages are already installed. I also tried:
`conda install -c conda-forge python` and
`pip3.9 install python`
None of them worked for me.

Comment: Please check if this works for you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63216201/how-to-install-python3-9-with-conda

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot.