# Update Python to 3.9 on Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I am trying to update python to 3.9 using the anaconda distribution using this command:

```py
conda install python==3.9.0
```

However, there is no output but an error. All of the other methods I have seen are extremely difficult, so is there an easier way of updating python (preferably using the terminal- I am on MacOS)? I am unsure if Python 3.9.0 is even on the condo distribution, since when you go to the Anaconda website, Anaconda comes pre-packaged with Python 3.8.

Comment: did you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/64234698/5014455

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
conda create -c conda-forge python=3.9 -n py39-demo
```

Comment: I have to activate the virtual environment right?

Comment: It would be up to you to decide. It's recommended to always create your projects inside a virutalenv