# How can I run both TensorFlow and Torch on Mac M1 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, tensorflow, pycharm, pytorch, apple-m1

I encounter some problems on my MacBook Pro M1. I thought it would be easier to start coding on it, apparently it's not a ML beast yet...

I need to use both PyTorch and TensorFlow on Python. I have installed [TensorFlow 2.0 for Mac OS](https://github.com/apple/tensorflow_macos).

The problem is: TensorFlow won't work when you use a x86_64 terminal. (So it doesn't work with PyCharm). However, I can import TensorFlow 2.0 from an arm terminal.
Paradoxically, PyTorch won't install on a arm terminal, only on a x86_64 terminal. So, on the same Python terminal, I'm not able to import both torch and TensorFlow 2.0.

Since [HuggingFace transformers](https://huggingface.co/transformers/) is crucial for me, and transformers needs both TensorFlow 2.0 and PyTorch, I need to go back on my old computer to code. I'm very disappointed!

Anyone successfully imported **both PyTorch and TensorFlow** on a **Mac M1** device?

And does anyone know if there is a way to force PyCharm to use an arm terminal, so I can use **TensorFlow 2.0 on PyCharm** on my M1 MPB?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried googling this? I see about 8-10 posts specifically talking about this. Just by googling "TensorFlow on mac M1". https://towardsdatascience.com/new-apple-silicon-m1-macbook-air-the-dream-laptop-for-machine-learning-engineers-a1590fbd170f

Comment: As you can read, I successful run TensorFlow on my Mac. The problem appears when I want to run TensorFlow + Torch (or probably any non optimized library for M1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some research, I found this answer: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/48145 .

So if someone tries to run both Tensorflow and Torch on Mac M1 with PyCharm Apple Silicon Version, here's how to proceed:

- Create a new virtual env with Tensorflow Mac OS
- From **terminal** (not from PyCharm, I got an error), with sudo rights, install the whl file for torch, from the GitHub issue: https://github.com/wizyoung/AppleSiliconSelfBuilds/blob/main/builds/torch-1.8.0a0-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl

Now you can open a PyCharm project with your freshly created virtual environment, and you'll be able to import both Tensorflow and Torch. However, a lot of librairies will be tricky to install like PyTorch...

Answer (score 2):

Try building from the source code as I was able to install on my MacBook pro 13 M1.
[PyTorch installation from source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64949501/pytorch-wont-install-in-pycharm-on-macos/65528845#65528845)

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I still got the same problem. I even tried with this: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/48145

Answer (score 1):

Now you can pip install PyTorch for Macs with M1!

https://pytorch.org/blog/introducing-accelerated-pytorch-training-on-mac/

You basically need to use this

```
pip3 install --pre torch torchvision torchaudio --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu
```

and replace "cuda" with "mps" in your code

Comment: doesn't "mps" uses cpu only and not gpu in m1?

Comment: @aquaman according to the PyTorch documentation 'mps' does use GPU (https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/mps.html)