# How to change my conda base environment from Python 3.7 to 3.9?

Tags: python, anaconda, version, conda

People have [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63216201/how-to-install-python3-9-with-conda#) how to install python 3.9 with anaconda, and the question was certainly answered.

BUT, what if I want to change my conda base environment from Python 3.7 to 3.9? Is there some simple magic?

Comment: I am actually not sure it is possible to change minor versions in environments, but especially for the base environment, I think you'd have to uninstall and re-install.

Answer (score -1):

there are actually 2 way. one of the easyiest way is to simply

1. Go to windows and type remove add or remove apps.
2. Search for python and simply uninstall from there.
3. Go to this link https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-394/
4. Now just install it and remember to add it to path

if you want to check the version simply type in cmd

```
python --version
```