# Cannot install python 3.9 using conda

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

I cannot install Python 3.9 using conda environment.

````
conda create --name demo-env python=3.9
WARNING: A conda environment already exists at '/XXXXXX'
Remove existing environment (y/[n])? y

Collecting package metadata: / Unable to retrieve repodata (404 error) for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noardone
Solving environment: failed

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - python=3.9

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/linux-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.```
````

Comment: This warning seems like the source of the problem: `Unable to retrieve repodata (404 error) for https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noardone`. There may be something wrong with your anaconda installation?

Comment: Actually, I just tried `curl https://repo.anaconda.com/` and that's giving me an error too, about their certificates. There may be a problem with the anaconda site at the moment, I'm not sure. My miniconda setup, however, did not have to fetch that url, so it worked fine, for what it's worth.

Comment: So what is the solution?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error, so that's hard to say. Try from a fresh miniconda install? Your command should have worked. (Although I always use == instead of just =, but I am pretty sure that won't change anything here.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install python with conda?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63216201/how-to-install-python-with-conda)

Answer (score 1):

As discussed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63216201/how-to-install-python-with-conda) post and based on your terminal output, python 3.9 doesn't exist there yet on any channels, and will need to be installed.

Perhaps try:

```
conda create -c conda-forge python=3.9 -n demo-env
```

Here, adding -c conda-forge will search the conda-forge channel

Comment: Standard conda channels already include both Python 3.9 and 3.10, so this should not be the problem.